# How to connect to a Sagemaker Jupyter notebook in PyCharm?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

PyCharm has launched a new 2023 version with [a new feature to remotely connect to a Jupyter notebook](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-jupyter-notebook.html#remote). The instructions in the tutorial say to type a server URL and a token:

[image: pycharm instructions]

My question is how do I get the relevant details (server URL and token) for my Sagemaker Studio Jupyter notebook.

Comment: What is the reason you would like to connect to Studio via PyCharm? Studio is designed to be used as a "Single ML IDE" it contains a bunch of features for all stages of the ML process and brings all SageMaker components into a unified single pane of glass.  You can access Studio via a pre-signed URL using CreateDomainPresignedUrl: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/create-presigned-domain-url.html

Comment: You can use Code Server to do it for VSCode - why not let the OP bring their own IDE? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/host-code-server-on-amazon-sagemaker

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this using Using [SageMaker SSH Helper](https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-ssh-helper#studio), after setting up an SSH connection between your local PyCharm and SageMaker studio notebook.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I never found it for the fainthearted.

Comment: it worked with SSH Helper. You can open an GitHub issue if you come across issues. The maintainer is responsive.